# How to trigger an event when the month changes on ngx-bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: angular, events, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

We are using ngx-bootstrap and we need a datepicker. So [ngx-bootstrap's Datepicker](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker) seems an obvious choice. We would like to load available dates for the calendar when the user navigates to the next month. For this we would like to subscribe to some event. I do not see such an event in the documentation. But I do see it in [the docs of (the regular) bootstrap variant datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changemonth).
I tried all sorts of things, even going into the dom and adding an eventlistener for the click event. That works, for 1 time, then probably the UI is rerendered and the button is recreated. The last resort seems to either use the MutationObserver (very painful) or download the source of the datepicker and hack it in (also painful). It seems a trivial thing: knowing when the month of the calendar changes. But I haven't got there yet. Any help is much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Hi! Seems like you got something going with adding listeners to those two buttons, are you combing it with the [visibility events](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#visibility-events)?

Answer (score 5):

It is possible by using the date pickers inner store. Yes I know it is a private. And therefore not the most clean solution perhaps. But since there seems to be no public API I was left with no other choice. I really needed to know when the user sees a different month on the calendar in order to effectively load the dates that are available for that month.

Here is the code to subscribe to the datepicker's store and get a notification when the view of the datepicker changes. You will be notified with a date when the month changes.

```
import { BsDatepickerInlineDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

interface BsDatePickerStoreView {
  date: Date,
  mode: keyof { 'day', 'month', 'year'}
}

interface BsDatePickerStoreData {
  view:BsDatePickerStoreView
}

export class BsDatePickerUtils
{
  public viewChanged = new BehaviorSubject<Date>(undefined);

  private lastKnownViewDate: Date = undefined;

  constructor(datePicker: BsDatepickerInlineDirective) {
    const store = (datePicker as any)._datepicker.instance._store.source as BehaviorSubject<BsDatePickerStoreData>;
    store.subscribe((data) => {
      const viewMode = data.view.mode;
      const date = data.view.date as Date;
      if (!this.lastKnownViewDate || this.lastKnownViewDate.toDateString() !== date.toDateString()) {
        if (data.view.mode === 'day') {
          this.lastKnownViewDate = date;
          this.viewChanged.next(data.view.date);
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

And here is a simplistic usage example

```
// Usage example
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
<div>
  <bs-datepicker-inline #datePicker></<bs-datepicker-inline>
</div>
  `
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild(BsDatepickerInlineDirective) datePicker: BsDatepickerInlineDirective;
  bsDatePickerUtils: BsDatePickerUtils;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.bsDatePickerUtils = new BsDatePickerUtils(this.datePicker);
    this.bsDatePickerUtils.viewChanged.subscribe(date => {
      console.log('Calendar changed: ' + date);
    });
  }
}
```