# Ngx-bootstrap datepicker: is there a way to set new available dates when I change month?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I'm trying to load available dates in bg-datepicker-inline component (using "datesEnabled" property). I used Mike's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64608171/how-to-trigger-an-event-when-the-month-changes-on-ngx-bootstrap-datepicker) to detect change month and it works. But when I change month I can't see new available dates.

This is my code.

*Child component .ts:*

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.bsDatePickerUtils = new BsDatePickerUtils(this.datePicker);
    this.bsDatePickerUtils.viewChanged.subscribe(date => {
        if (this.today.getMonth() === date?.getMonth()) {
            this.onChangeMonth(this.today);
        } else {
            this.onChangeMonth(date);
        }
    });
}

onChangeMonth(date: Date) {
    this.monthChange.emit(date);
}
```

*Child component .html*

```
<bs-datepicker-inline #datepicker id="datepicker" style="width: 100%" [minDate]="today" [bsConfig]="bsConfig" [datesEnabled]="enabledDates" [isDisabled]="isDisabled" (bsValueChange)="serviceType != null && getSlots($event)"></bs-datepicker-inline>
```

*Parent component .ts*

```
enabledDates: Date[] = [];
isDisabled: boolean = false;

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        if (this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state) {
            this.selectedInstance = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.selectedInstance;
            this.enabledDates = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.enabledDates;
            this.serviceType = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.serviceType;
            this.isInDB = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.isInDB;
            this.isStrutturaOK = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.isStrutturaValida;
        }
    });
}

getAvaiableDays(date: Date) {
    this.saltacodaService.disponibilitaGiorno(this.serviceType, this.selectedInstance.value, this.formattingDate(new Date(date), 'nospace')).subscribe((data) => {
        if (data.result) {
            this.enabledDates = [];
            this.enabledDates = this.getEnabledDatesForMonth(data.giorni, date);
            this.isDisabled = false;
        } else {
            this.isDisabled = true;
        }
    });
}

getEnabledDatesForMonth(arrayDates: string[], date: Date): Date[] {
    let result: Date[] = [];
    let ar: Date[] = [];
    const monthSelected = date.getMonth();
    for (let ad of arrayDates) {
        ar.push(this.strToDate(ad));
    }
    result = ar.filter(x => x.getMonth() === monthSelected);
    return result;
}

formattingDate(date, type) {
    let d = new Date(date);
    if (type == 'nospace') {
        return formatDate(d, 'yyyyMMdd', 'en-US');
    } else {
        return formatDate(d, 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'en-US');
    }
}

strToDate(str) {
    let d = str.substring(6, 8);
    let m = str.substring(4, 6);
    let y = str.substring(0, 4);
    let date = new Date(y, m - 1, d);
    return date;
}
```

*Parent component .html*

```
<ng-container> 
<app-datepicker-inline [enabledDates]="enabledDates" (monthChange)="getAvaiableDays($event)" [serviceType]="serviceType" (selectDate)="getSlots($event)" [isDisabled]="isDisabled"> 
</app-datepicker-inline> 
</ng-container>
```

Ngx-bootstrap: version 8.0.0

Any suggestions?

Thanks